# Getting error popup when an website solution opened in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, comexception

I am getting below error when a website solution is opened in Visual Studio 2017

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80041FEC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041FEC 
    at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsSolutionBuildOrderPrivate.GetBuildOrderList(Boolean fForceRecalculation, UInt32 cProjects, VsProjectBuildOrder[] pBuildOrder, UInt32& pValidationId)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg.Shims.TaskListBase.RecalculateProjectRank()
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg.Shims.TaskListBase.OnEntriesChanged(Object sender, EntriesChangedEventArgs e)
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Comment: Did you try doing a repair on visual studio?

Comment: Yes, I did. But no luck :(

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: not resolved yet. It just works even though the error is pops up.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

https://medium.com/@joni2nja/the-case-of-visual-studio-2017-version-15-8-and-invalid-docker-compose-file-92ace224eea1

Basically I had a file for docker that was referencing a file that didn't exist.  Once I fixed that reference, it stopped producing this popup.

Now it may not be docker for you, and something totally different, where you have a reference to a file a that doesn't exist.  Unfortunately nothing in the log says what the file reference to is.